# Symfony 2.8: how to access $data sent to view in the onKernelResponse EventListener?

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-2.8

I've created a EventListener for onKernelResponse:

```
    <?php

namespace Webprogest\More\SharedBundle\EventListener;

use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Event\GetResponseEvent;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernel;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernelInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\SecurityContextInterface;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\Session;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerInterface;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Event\FilterResponseEvent;

class RequestListener
{

    protected $sc;
    private $container;

    public function __construct(ContainerInterface $container)
    {
        $this->container = $container;
    }

    public function onKernelResponse(FilterResponseEvent $event)
    {
        $response = $event->getResponse();
        var_dump($response);
    }
}
```

This is my service.yml:

```
kernel.listener.your_listener_name:
        class: Webprogest\More\SharedBundle\EventListener\RequestListener
        arguments: ["@service_container"]
        tags:
            - { name: kernel.event_listener, event: kernel.request, method: onKernelRequest }
            - { name: kernel.event_listener, event: kernel.response, method: onKernelResponse }
```

My question is: of course 99% of times this Event is triggered after the Controller execution, just before calling the view. So: how can I access the $data array I'm sending to the view on my controller?
Thanks

Comment: Response object is already created, so you don't have access to $data array. What's the goal?

Comment: Thanks Denis. Basically, my event listener function records in sessions the list of all the routes visited by the user, storing for each route the route_name, route_params and a custom user friendly title. The user frieny title already got generated on the controller and sent to view through the $data array. So, rather than generating it again in the event listener, I would like tl read it from the controller...